# app-debug.apk is crashing while I install it manually on my Android device

Tags: android, crash, apk

My app is running fine on Android device when I run project from Android studio. But when I install app-debug.apk manually on my device then app is crashing on starting. And app-debug-unaligned.apk is not generating. 
Kindly give any solution, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to Generate build apk and try build apk

Comment: Yes it's working now. Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Delete `debug.apk`  from output folder under build in app.  and generate again and install .

Comment: still crashing. deleted the debub.apk from ouput. but still it crash. while running well on emulator

Comment: @Goblinシ Unisntall old APK form device and try with build clean and Rebuild fucntions.

Comment: actually, if i install on marshmallow device its working fine, but on nougat devices its crashing and sometimes its started working and opening. also, if i using nougat emulator on android studio its working smooth. i cant ask question thats why i cant put my code. if needed i can send the gradle and manifest code

Comment: i have done all the things mentioned in this question. problem is still there

Answer (score 7):

I resolved this issue by unchecking **instant run** from Settings in android Studio.

Comment: Choosing Build > Build APK from the Android Studio menu should allow the complete APK file to be generated, even if Instant Run is on.

Comment: i have generated the apk from build only, still it crashing

Comment: @Goblin 
Had you unchecked the instant run from settings?

Comment: actually, if i install on marshmallow device its working fine, but on nougat devices its crashing and sometimes its started working and opening. also, if i using nougat emulator on android studio its working smooth. i cant ask question thats why i cant put my code. if needed i can send the gradle and manifest code

Comment: You saved my time dude!!!. I am having this problem past 3 months. But your idea made solve my problem. Thank you dude

Answer (score 3):

First install your apk in your mobile and then try using the app.
The app gets crashed on some click event.
perform that click and check the android monitor for error and proceed resolving based on ur error.

For me it worked when i have given public modifier to onclick methods

Answer (score 1):

Mostly the issue comes due to presence of older application with same **package name** or different **version number**. 
Also, if you are sharing the apk using whatsapp, its likely to happen that apk wont install properly.
And lastly improper build can also cause the issue. So to sum up-

> 1. Uninstall previous app
> 2. Check for version conflicts
> 3. Avoid sharing apk through whatsapp
> 4. Clean project
> 5. Build Apk and then distribute
> 6. Build signed Apk and then try installing(Recommended)