# Gradle:3.0.1 "Build APK(s)" builds apk with NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-install-apk

gradle:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
```

I make:

1. Instant run is disabled
2. Build->Clean Project
3. Build->Build APK(s)
4. adb install app-debug.apk
5. Launch application

Error in log:

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example, PID: 23753
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.example.TheApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.TheApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.example-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:676)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6289)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:221)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1860)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.TheApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.example-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1004)
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:666)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6289)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:221)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1860)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.TheApplication
at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

Comment: is your instant run enabled or disabled ? and also can you post your gradle file ?

Comment: Possible answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/43109746/2298357

Comment: As @Umair said, could you provide your Gradle file please?

Comment: @PankajKantPatel, thank you

Comment: This is usually happens when the configuration for multidex is not right. You need to check how you configure the multidex.

Answer (score 0):

**Go to File->Setting->Instant Run unchecked checkbox of Instance Run ->Press Apply**
Remove build folder ,clean and Rebuild project

After this my problem is resolved

Answer (score 0):

When I have faced similar error I found that my missing class was in another dex file.

I simple added multidex-config.pro file (replace "com.sample.package" with you package)

```
-keep class com.sample.package.** { *; }
```

and added multiDexKeepProguard in my build.gradle

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            multiDexKeepProguard(new File("multidex-config.pro"))
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            versionNameSuffix "-debug"
        }

        release {
            multiDexKeepProguard(new File("multidex-config.pro"))
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
```

when gradle build apk file, it will package classes in one dex file

hope it helps